# How to fix weird image coming from different color space

Tags: opencv, image-processing, color-space

I’ve been doing assignment for image processing 
I want to display the image in different color space.
I know there’s a function cvtColor in OPenCv to covert it
And after doing it  I use the imshow and give really weird image which I’m not surprised at all since imshow accept the BGR image.
My question is that is there any possibility that when 
I covert the RGB image into for example HSI model and then use imshow without getting weird image? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you will get weird images with all the colorspaces other than BGR, however you can create a function that converts it to bgr and displays it with imshow. In some cases you can display one of the channels to get some feedback of it, for example the S channel in HSI or the I channel.

Comment: convert back to BGR... what do you expect? It is still the image, just a different color space. So e.g. if you convert to HSV and display it correctly, it will just look the same (maybe some artifacts because of rounding problems) as if you rendered the BGR image directly.

Comment: @Micka yeah my question is how to display it correctly?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "correctly". If you want to show the quality loss because of precision loss (e.g. in YUV), you can first convert to YUV and then convert back to BGR and imshow it. If you want to split for example the channels in an HSV image and display only the hue information, you could replace each hue value by a single BGR value and render it with imshow. It really depends on what you mean by "correctly rendering" and what you want to show.

Comment: Screens work with BGR (often with sRGB standard), so at the end, the image should be converted again to BGR. Every other colour space is just for working (e.g. linear, LAB, HSV, etc.) or for transition/compression (LAB, LUV, PAL, NTSC, ...). Imshow send the image buffer which will be interpreted as BGR.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi OK,got it Thanks!so clear~~~